# How can I show comments of clicked feed only

Tags: javascript, html, angular, graphql

I'm stuck in a situation, in a nested loop. The top loop iterating over the `Feeds` array and every `feed` in `Feeds` have **comments** array. This **comments** is used for inner loop.

My problem is, I have  **Comment button** and on click of that button, I want to show the list of **comments** only for that feed post. But instead of showing comments on current feed post, it is showing comments for all other feeds also, that's because of use of only one `Boolean` variable `showComments` created inside `.ts` file.

So how can make that work for only the given context **Feed post**?

**HTML**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let feed of feeds">
  <div class="ed-card ed-card-feed">
    <div class="ed-card-feed--footer">
      <div class="card-feed-values">
        <a class="mr-4"><span>{{feed.likes_count}}</span> Likes</a>
        <a><span>{{feed.comments_count}}</span> Comments</a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-feed-actions">
        <a class="mr-5" (click)="likePost(feed.id)"><span></span> Like</a>
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mr-5" (click)="showComments = true"><span></span> Comment button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    // Below  div needs to be open for that particular feed only
    <div *ngIf="showComments" class="ed-card-feed--comments">
      <div class="feed-comments-list">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let comment of feed.comments?.edges">
          <div class="comment-list-item">
            <p class="comment-box mt-1">
              {{comment.node?.body}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

P.S. - Please don't confuse with `feed.comments?.edges` that's just because of `GraphQL`. It is just an array.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain an array of `showComments[]` equal to size of `feeds` with initially set to false. `showComments[false,false...]`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let feed of feeds; let myIndex = index"">
 //code here
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mr-5" (click)="showComments[myindex] = true"><span></span> Comment button</a>
```

//check if true

```
<div *ngIf="showComments[myindex] === true" class="ed-card-feed--comments">
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a boolean, you can define a `selectedFeeds` array:

```
selectedFeeds = new Array<Feed>();
```

In the template, you add the feed that has been clicked to `selectedFeeds`:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mr-5" (click)="selectedFeeds.push(feed)>Comment button</a>
```

and you filter the comments according to the selected feeds:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedFeeds.indexOf(feed) >= 0" class="ed-card-feed--comments">
```

Comment: It will work but everytime the feed will change the previous feed comment-box will be closed

Comment: The question mentioned that you wanted to see the comments "only for that feed post". I modified my answer to allow the selection of multiple feeds.

Comment: pushing into selectedFeeds is also a good way. Just might cost space if feed object is huge.

Comment: @Helpinghand - Not really. It only adds a Feed pointer to the array, not the Feed content.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to separate the code to different components. And since each of the component will have it's own instance of comments - you won't have a problem creating a local variable and showing/displaying the comments in there.

I've created an example of how it can be implemented: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwrgqd)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let feed of feeds">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="toggleComments(feed)">Comment button</a>
    <div *ngIf="feed.showComments" class="ed-card-feed--comments">
</ng-container>
```

Js file

```
toggleComments(feed) {
   feed.showComments = true // (feed.showComments = !feed.showComments => to show or hide (toggle))
}
```